# Python cyclical import between peer nodes in a graph

Tags: python

base/dir1/a.py

```
from base.dir2.b import B

class A:
    def get_peer(self):
        return B()
```

base/dir2/b.py

```
from base.dir1.a import A

class B:
    def get_peer(self):
        return A()
```

This actually represents a peer relationship in a very complex tree. A is a type of leaf node, B is another type of leaf node. They can have each other as peers.

This doesn't work as I have a cyclical import.

I'm trying to figure out what is the optimal project structure such that A & B can both instantiate each other without causing cyclical imports.

Edit: I'd really like a solution that doesn't look like this:

```
import base

class A:
    def get_peer(self):
        return base.dir2.b.B()
```

That is a serious mess in the actual code when I start going down that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can import the module instead of the class it should work properly.

You should just be able to do

```
import base.dir2.b as b
```

to shorten the name to something manageable.

Comment: So the problem with that is that my code now becomes a mess of:

c = base.dir2.b.B()

Keep in mind this is simplified in the actual code the names are longer and they are referenced multiple times in a single statement. It's ridiculously unwieldy.

Comment: @amirpc `import ridiculously.long.name.of.module as shortname`

Answer (score 1):

It fails 'cause it tries to resolve the imports at "compile time". If you do a late import, it works. The cost of the late import (after the first time) is only a lookup in sys.modules, so there's no reason to not do it, other than it being funky. Good comments explaining why you're being funky helps tho'.

```
# A.py
from base.d1 import B

class A:
    def get_peer(self):
        return B()

# B.py
class B:
    def get_peer(self):
        from base.d2 import A
        return A()

# If you want to be cool and make hard-to-maintain code to reuse crappy pattern
import importlib

class Base(object):
    peer = None
    def get_peer(self):
        if not self.peer:
            raise ValueError("Missing peer")
        mod = '.'.join(self.peer.split('.')[:-1])
        cls = self.peer.split('.')[-1]
        return getattr(importlib.__import__(mod), cls)

class A(Base):
    peer = 'base.d2.B'
```

Comment: This is what I settled on. The version without the helper.